# openpyxl - edit the last value of a row

Tags: python, tkinter, openpyxl

I can't seem to get around this:

I want to access the last cell in a given column in order to add a value to it. But my code doesn't work:

```
from tkinter import *
import datetime
import openpyxl 
import os


wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("TimeSheet.xlsx", use_iterators=True)
ws1 = wb.get_sheet_by_name("TimeSheet")



master = Tk()

firstDate = Entry(master)
firstDate.pack()

firstDate.focus_set()


def date_receiving():

    totalRows = 0
    receivingDate = firstDate.get()
    for rowNum in ws1.iter_rows("B6:B"+str(ws1.max_row)):
        for cell in rowNum:
            print(cell)
        cellule = ws1.cell(row=rowNum, column=2).value
        if cellule != "":
            totalRows += 1
            print(totalRows)
        else:
            break
```

I've tried a few things but can't find the last empty cell. Please help!

Thanks,

Comment: You won't be able to edit anything if you use read-only mode.

Comment: @CharlieClark - is the way I open the file in read-only? How can I see/change that? So with what I'm doing I can find the row after the last but won't be able to edit it anyway right?

Comment: Yes. We've renamed the parameter from `use_iterators` to `read_only` to make this clearer.

Comment: I had no idea. Thanks for your help!
And great job! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some code which should get you the number of the last empty cell as `maxBlank`. Let me know how it works for you.

```
from Tkinter import *
import datetime
import openpyxl 
import os


wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("TimeSheet.xlsx", use_iterators=True)
ws1 = wb.get_sheet_by_name("TimeSheet")



master = Tk()

firstDate = Entry(master)
firstDate.pack()

firstDate.focus_set()


def date_receiving():

    maxBlank = -1
    for rowNum in ws1.iter_rows("B6:B"+str(ws1.max_row)):
        for cell in rowNum:
            if cell.internal_value == None:
                if cell.row > maxBlank:
                    maxBlank =  cell.row
    print maxBlank
```

Comment: Thanks for answering.

I only had to modify the following:
    'maxBlank = -1
    for rowNum in ws1.iter_rows("B23:B"+str(ws1.max_row)):
        for cell in rowNum:
            if cell.value == None:
                if cell.row > maxBlank:
                    maxBlank =  cell.row
                    break
        else:
            continue
        break'
Add breaks so it can exit both loops.
Works great! Thank you!